# About losing HTTP Requests

Tags: apache, http, tomcat, get

I have a server to which my client sends a HTTP GET request with some values. The server on its end simply stores these values to a database.

Now, I am observing that sometimes I do not observe these values in the database. One of the following could have happened:

1. The client never sent it
2. The server never received it
3. The server failed in writing to the database

My strongest doubt is that the reason is 2 - but I am unable to explain it completely. Since this is an HTTP request (which means there is TCP underneath) reliable delivery of the GET request should be guaranteed, right? Is it possible that even though I send a GET request to the server - it was never received by the server? If yes, what is TCP doing there?

Or, can I confidently assert that if the server is up and running and everything sent to the server is written to the database, then the absence of the details of the GET request in the database means the client never sent it?

Not sure if the details will help - but I am running a tomcat server and I am just sending a name-value pair through the get request.

Comment: Whatever language you use to make http request, you have to check the result from that operation, and print it or log it...

Comment: So, for example, there was some network issue and the packet never reached the server (and hence I will not get any response from the server) - at least this condition should be handled by the TCP - i.e. - resend the packet - till we get a response?

Comment: Yes, of corse... At worst, you'll receive a timeout error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you seem to be missing. First of all, yes, if TCP finishes successfully, you pretty much have a guarantee that your message (i.e. the TCP payload) has reached the other side: TCP assures that it will take care of lost packages and the order in which packages arrive. However, this is not universially failproof, as there are still things beyond the powers of TCP (think of a physical disconnect by cutting through an ethernet cable). There is also no assertion regarding the syntactical correctness of the protocol "above." Any checks beyond delivering a bit-perfect copy is simply not TCP's concern.

So, there is a chance that the requests issued by your client are faulty or that they are indeed correct but not parsed correctly by your server. Former is striking me as more likely as latter one as Tomcat is a very mature piece of software. I think it would help tremendously if you would record and analyse some of your generated traffic through e.g. [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/).

You do not really mention what database you have in use. But there are some sacrificing [acid](/questions/tagged/acid)-compliance in favour of increased write speeds. The nature of these databases brings it that you can never be really sure wether something actually got written to disk or is still residing in some buffer in memory. Should you happen to use such a db, this were another line of investigation.

Programmatically, I advise you take the following steps when dealing with HTTP traffic:

- Has writing to the socket finishes without error?
- Could a response be read from the socket?
- Does the response carry a code in the 2xx range (indicating a successful operation)?

If any of these fail, you should really log something.

On a realated note, what you are doing there does not call for the [`GET`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1) method but for [`POST`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3) as you are changing application state. Consider it as a nice-to-have ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, I am currently working with an infrastructure someone else wrote, so I am not sure if I have the liberty to change fundamental things like changing the GET calls to POST calls. However, I am curious as to why do you call modifying the GET to POST as a nice-to-have. Is it purely for convention reasons (use things are they meant to be used) or are there some direct advantages in functionality as well?

Comment: @TheBlueNotebook `POST` were closer to the HTTP specs as `GET` is only meant to be used for information retrieval, not not for changing application state. There are some circumstances where `GET` is allowed to do so, but those do not apply to your use case IMHO. And there is no immediate advantage. In fact, `POST` requires some more effort to be set up. I considered it nice-to-have in face of the problems you are experiencing currently.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the specifics, you can break it down into two parts. The HTTP request and the DB write. The client will receive a 200 OK response from the server when its GET request has been acknowledged. I've written code under Tomcat to connect to a MySQL DB using DAO. In the case of a failure an exception would be thrown and logged. Which ever method you're using, you'll want to figure out how failures are logged.